# Framework7 with Cordova Vertical Scrolling Not Working on iOS

Tags: ios, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 for the first time in a Cordova iOS application and I really like the look of the UI but I have run into an issue where the page will not scroll vertically that I can not figure out.  I have attempted to debug the code by replacing 'overflow:hidden' in places with 'overflow:auto' but that does not seem to resolve the issue.

Has anyone else run into this before?  Any help wuold be greatly appreciated as I am really stumped on this one.

EDIT: I think I have narrowed down the issue to the overflow:hidden CSS attribute on the .view and .pages classes.  If I remove that attribute the page scrolls, but now the header and footer are not attached to the top and bottom of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out that the issue was caused by missing the page-content div.  I added this div just after the data-page="index and it started to scroll.

Example:

```
<div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
    <div data-page="index" class="page">   /* this is what I was missing */
        <div class="page-content">
            /* content here */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```